# NamedCredentials update after sandbox refresh

Tags: namedcredentials, sandbox-refresh

I have some Custom Settings and Named credentials configured since I make call outs to external systems. But every time I refresh any of my sandbox, I have to manually update the Custom Settings and Named Credentials.  I tried to create a Sandbox template but couldn't find a way to exclude Named Credentials and Custom Settings there. Also, thought of writing an APEX class which I can execute after refresh but I think Custom Settings can be updated via APEX but since Named Credentials is a read only object, I didn't find this option much suitable as well. Could someone advise what is the best practice to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See Mohith's answer - you use the Apex wrapper on the Metadata API (available in GitHub) and update the [NamedCredential metadata resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_namedcredential.htm?search_text=namedcredential). You don't use normal Apex DML, metadata API is done via callout

Answer (score 3):

One of the approaches I can think of is to Use Salesforce [metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) like one maintained by Financial Force to implement logic to update named credentials .

You will need to put the logic inside class implementing SandboxPostCopy interface

```
global class UpdateNamedCredential implements SandboxPostCopy {
   global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
      System.debug('Hello Tester Pester ' + context.organizationId()
       + ' ' + context.sandboxId() + context.sandboxName());
      // Insert logic here to update named credential

  }
 }
```

Comment: Mohit - thanks for the details. I tried this approach as well but the challenge I am facing is how to update Named Credentials using APEX. You can reference Named Credentials in callouts but I am not aware of any apex code which can query and update the Named Credentials.

Comment: You will need to import financial force wrapper for metadata api and that would allow you to edit the named credential .

Comment: can you share sample code for reference?